# Minute format php

Tags: php, time

how can I just get the format in minutes instead of for example 01:10:33 to get 70:33, or 00:30:01 to get 30:01.
 i get value $sec from array in seconds

["Duration"]=>int(5382) or 
  ["No_ofMinutes"]=> string(4) "89.7"

This is my code,

```
echo gmdate('H:i:s', $sec);
```

and I need only ('mm:ss')

thank you all for your help.

Comment: Multiple the hours by `60` then add it to the minutes? Although `gmdate` is not the number of hours, it is the time `01` is one o'clock, not one hour.

Answer (score 1):

You can get minutes like following

```
gmdate("i")
```

Comment: echo gmdate('i:s', $sec); i set this up and it does the job i want, i hope sae the formatting is correct too

Answer (score 0):

I think you can generate it from the `$sec`.

```
$sec = 1801;
$m = floor($sec / 60);
$s = $sec % 60;

$m = $m < 10 ? '0' . $m : $m;
$s = $s < 10 ? '0' . $s : $m;

$time = $m . ':' . $s;

echo $time;
```

Comment: I corrected my question, I believe there is some easier form of conversion.